# How to replicate index range for 4 separate data elements

Tags: vba, indexing, range

I'm using an Index to loop through non blank records in another worksheet and pull through 2 values which works fine.
I now need to duplicate these rows so each row appears 4 times with a 3rd column containing the 4 company names (Company1, Commpany2, Company3 and Company4).
We therefore end up with 4 times the number of records as the source sheet which should look like the following:

[image]

My current code is:

```
Sub Address_Raw()
    Dim dataBook As Workbook
    Dim Address_Raw As Worksheet, Del_Tax As Worksheet
    Dim dataSource As Range, dataDest As Range
    Dim sourceDataRowCount As Integer, index As Integer

    Set dataBook = Application.ThisWorkbook
    Set sheetSource = dataBook.Sheets("Address_Raw")
    Set sheetDest = dataBook.Sheets("Del_Tax")

    Set dataSource = sheetSource.Range("B4", _
                    sheetSource.Range("B90000").End(xlUp))
    sourceDataRowCount = dataSource.Rows.Count

    Set dataDest = sheetDest.Range("B13", "B" & _
                                sourceDataRowCount)

    For index = 1 To sourceDataRowCount
      dataDest(index, 1).Value = dataSource(index, 1).Value
      dataDest(index, 2).Value = dataSource(index, 2).Value

    Next index

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add an inner loop in the for loop. Something like this (untested):

```
destIndex = 1
For index = 1 To sourceDataRowCount
   For j = 1 to 4
     dataDest(destIndex, 1).Value = dataSource(index, 1).Value
     dataDest(destIndex, 2).Value = dataSource(index, j + 1).Value
     destIndex = destIndex + 1
   Next j
Next index
```

Comment: Apologies Sam but I'm not really understanding this, if you can help me that would be much appreciated.
So The Company Names are names which are not currently listed on the sourcedata sheet. The first 2 columns are in the source sheet, I want to duplicate each of those rows 4 times and add in the 4 company names (the same 4 all the way down)
When I tried your code, it pulled the last Customer name, and then the data in the 3 columns to the right of this in the source data transposed into a column.
Do I need to add anything else such as the source data?

Comment: I didn't put that much effort into understanding the logic you need. A general piece of advice here is to put a breakpoint at the line after `For j` and examine the values of destIndex and index. Find out what they are at each iteration and figure out what you want them to be. Once you have that understanding you will either know how to solve it, or how to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Oh my life, this took some getting my head around, but finally solved it with a couple of additional variables... thank you.  Final code:

Comment: it won't let me add the code now as too many characters and CTRL + K edits the address bar but its sorted... thank you